# Is there a way to keep a copy of our highlighting in iBooks? (email it or print it)

Tags: books

In iBooks, we can see a list of our highlighting and added notes to an ebook, but when we email it, so as to keep a copy for ourselves, only the added notes that we wrote is emailed.  The highlighting is not.

Is there a way to keep a copy of what we highlighted as well?  We can take a snapshot of the iPad screen, but that's a photo instead of text.

There is also a "Print" option, although I don't have any printer linked up for the iPad to use.  Can that Print option print highlighting, or print it as a PDF doc?  Or any other possible way to keep a copy of our highlighting and notes?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I print my books and PDFs from iBooks?
>
> Yes, you can print PDFs and notes you've entered from iBooks, but the
>   option to print ePub books is not available.2 You can also email PDFs
>   and notes you have written from iBooks.
>
> Can I highlight text and make notes?
>
> iBooks includes built-in Highlight and Note features. Highlight any
>   word or passage of text within a book. You can also create a Note from
>   your highlighted selection. Review your Highlights and Notes by
>   tapping the Table of Contents button and then tapping Bookmarks.
>   Highlights and Notes appear in their own section under Bookmarks.

source: [apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4059?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)
Doesn't seem to be a straight yes/no answer for printing of the highlighted area, but you can turn a highlighted area into a note, which will print/email.

Comment: In my case, the "export" button is disabled, and I can't export the notes :(

Answer (score 0):

Using iBooks 3.0 and iOS6 , you can share annotations to Facebook (if that’s a problem, configure access to be private-only). This gives you an archive of all notes… on Facebook.

Not a good solution but still usable.